# Embedding multiple twitter streams into a website with API 1.1

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter

I used to embed twitter into clients websites using the seaofclouds plugin which was very effective but now it has changed and you need keys I'm guessing there are limits to how you can use the API.  Here are 2 scenarios that I would like to use in my website:

1. To set up multiple user profile pages and embed their twitter stream (5 Tweets) directly into the profile with a link to each users main Twitter page.
2. To have a Tweet Me style box where visitors to my website can add a message directly to my twitter page without them having to leave and use twitter itself. I have seen this on the official twitter plugin which can be used from the site but I don't want the tweets in there - Just the message me box

Are these possible and does anyone know how they can be done?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use their feature known as "dynamic timeline selection". It lets you use one widget ID for all twitter streams as opposed to setting up a widget for each user manually.

- https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/1841
- https://dev.twitter.com/docs/embedded-timelines#timeline-selection